# Create android deep links

Tags: android, firebase

I created deep link that looks like this:
https://sharetips.app.goo.gl?amv=0&apn=reznik.com.sharetipsandgetmoney&link=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dreznik.com.sharetipsandgetmoney

When i open this link i redirect to unknow page ( code: 404 ).

I use this filter in my AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
            android:host="play.google.com"
            android:scheme="https"
            android:pathPattern=".*" />
</intent-filter>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the filter except you shouldn't use it because you're claiming that your app should handle all https://play.google.com links. And the PlayStore app is already doing it.

You should first have a valid link to get the deep link working.

Can you explain what you want to achieve with deep link here?